# Issues with calling a codeBehind function from the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

So an ASP.net project that someone else built about four years ago in Visual Studios 2008 now needs some of its hard coded values changed, and it's my task to rebuild it. I am using visual studios 2012.

I do not have a good grasp of ASP, as this is not what I normally do. I am having issues with the following bit of (redacted) code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" 
CodeBehind="CourseList.aspx.cs" Inherits="ah.CourseList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<% writeCourseList(); %> <!--Compiler complains -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Visual studios says that "The name 'writeCourseList' does not exist in the current context"

I am confused, as writeCourseList is a public method in class CourseList. Also, this code must have compiled at one point since it works on the live server. CourseList class:

```
namespace ah{
    public partial class CourseList: System.Web.UI.Page{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void writeCourseList()
        { //do stuff}
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, please feel free to advise me on how to better ask this question. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to compile? What other compiler errors are you getting? Make sure all the project references are valid.

Comment: Oded makes a good point:  just because VS Intellisense objects to something, doesn't always mean it will fail at runtime.  Does this code fail to compile?  Fail on execution locally?

Comment: The best thing about ASP.NET is that you virtually never need to use inline code tags.  Just add a placeholder or label where the inline tag currently is and set it's content in the code behind.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really even consider that the file could run despite the compiler warnings, as I assumed it just didn't know which method to call. It actually worked just fine. However, I think I will try to edit the code so that it adheres to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public string writeCourseList()
{
    return "this is a course list";
}
```

You need to return a string from the method when you want to use inline asp.net tags.

[inline asp.net tags... sorting them all out (<%$, <%=, <%, <%#, etc.)](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

But instead i would not use this classis asp style. You should use web databound controls like `GridView, Repeater, ListView,DataList` or a simple [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) instead.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
     {
          listBox1.DataSource = getAllListCourses(); // f.e. a DataTable
          listBox1.DataTextField  = "TextColumn";
          listBox1.DataValueField = "IdColumn";
          listBox1.DataBind();
     }
}
```

You can also [`add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s6873c.aspx) [`ListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) manually:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Course-name","ID"));
```

Comment: From the code (usage and return type) and the OP description, I think this is simply a function that is expected to be called, rather than one that renders anything.